# Como detectar funções no browser

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, aplicação-web, navegador-de-internet

Estou desenvolvendo um web scrapper em python que vai pegar os dados de um gráfico de ações a cada 30 min e me enviar um e-mail falando se a ação variou positivamente ou negativamente, porém, me dei com o seguinte problema: Como eu pego os dados do canvas da ação? Sei que há uma função (provavelmente JS) que insere os novos valores no canvas, e é justamente aqui que vem a minha dúvida, tem como eu ver pelo browser, ou até mesmo pelo IDE qual função está atualizando o canvas?

Esse é o site: http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/cotacoes/

E esse é todo o código que eu fiz até agora:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/cotacoes/'

site = requests.get(url=url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')

print(len(scripts))
```

Retorna 40 que são todas as  scripts que tem na página.

Muitas são apenas a tag  indicando o arquivo da função sem o corpo da função em si e para análisar todas as 40 tags e procurar cada diretório vai ser no mínimo demorado, por isso desde já agradeço se os senhores(a) souberem uma forma de ver a função que atualiza esse canvas

Answer (score 2):

O BeautifulSoup não permite ler javascript. Se conseguir extrair o texto do script que procura teria que utilizar regex para obter o valor desejado.
Para ler código javascript existe o PhantomJS ou o Selenium.